# Automatically display the last part of the text (received from outside) in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am developing a web page using ReactJS. In this webpage, I have a div that should emulate a console. The text to display in the console comes from outside with SocketIO. The messages are maintained in an array that gets updated every time that a new message arrives.

the problem is that I would like to see the coming messages without the necessity to scroll down every time (as it happens in a real console, messages are appended and the 'page' of the console goes down to display it). Is it possible?

Thank you so much and kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setInterval` to scroll automatically, the below code scrolls at every 5 seconds.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  var div= document.getElementById('consolediv');
  div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I used this solution. By the way I put the code for the scrolling in the componentDidUpdate() function of React component. This function is called every time after that the console get rendered (and so every time that a new message arrives).

Answer (score 1):

You can probably achieve this by using a bit of CSS.

I've created a JSFiddle so you can test it out ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/bornasepic/1u5kaxdp/1/)).

Essentially you need to apply,

```
overflow: auto; 
display:flex; 
flex-direction:column-reverse;
```

to your container div. Also, I suggest adding an extra wrapper div to not have the `flex-direction:column-reverse;` actually reverse anything.

I haven't tested it out with dynamic content from SocketIO but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.